# Npgsql strange exception

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, exception, npgsql

This is an example given in the manual. When I try the same, i get umpteen exceptions. What is the mistake in this.

```
using(NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connstring"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select command", conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("column1", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
        command.Parameters[0].Value = 4;
        using(NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dr.Read();
            Console.Write("{0} \t", dr[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception :

```
System exception System.IO.IOException: I/O error occurred.
at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__a.MoveNext()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.IterateThroughAllResponses(IEnumerable`1 ienum)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.Query(NpgsqlConnector context, NpgsqlCommand command)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Query(NpgsqlCommand queryCommand)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReleaseRegisteredListen()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReleaseResources()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.UngetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection, NpgsqlConnector Connector)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.ReleasePooledConnectorInternal(NpgsqlConnection Connection, NpgsqlConnector Connector)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.ReleasePooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection, NpgsqlConnector Connector)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.ReleaseConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection, NpgsqlConnector Connector)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Close()
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
```

Now this works correctly. What's the difference :

```
using(NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connstring"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select command", conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("column1", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
        command.Parameters[0].Value = 4;
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();            
        dr.Read();
        Console.Write("{0} \t", dr[0]);
    }
}
```

why datareader cannot be used with Idisposable ?

Comment: Do you get any results before the exception, and are there any errors in the postgres logs? `NpgsqlState.IterateThroughAllResponses` is in parsing non-result queries's responses and there are internal queries sent when a connection is being cleaned-up. I think here though, either Npgsql has the bug or there is a bug in your code (perhaps your connection string or query which you don't give in your example code is where the bug lies), and then Npgsql handles it badly with a message from its internals rather than a good explanation for the problem.

Comment: Also, could you show your real `"connstring"` and `"select command"` with just the username, servername, and password changed to XXXX. Obviously you don't want to publish that, but the problem could lie there.

Comment: This seems to be a problem in Npgsql where it is not handling correctly an error situation. The strange part is why you are getting IOExceptions when disposing a connection. Do you disconnect from server while running your program?

Comment: @FranciscoJunior : I have edited the question because it works if datareader is not used with a using ( that is not idisposable). Please check and suggest why this doesn't happen properly.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. If anything it should be the other way around. It's definitely not correct for Npgsql to do this. There might be a bug in your code (again, can wee see the real strings?) and there might not, but either way Npgsql shouldn't react like that. It's definitely one for the bug-list.

Comment: connstring = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=6001;User Id=test_test;Password=xxxxx;database=db_test"

and query is "select column1 from table1 where id = xvalue" and sometimes I use procedures , "select value1,value2 from schema.function(:xvalue,:yvalue)"   and then add parameters to it. 

The question is why does it work when it is not disposed and why not for using(NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()). It is a reason for worry !

Comment: @FranciscoJunior There is program in the NPGSQL manual like how it is in my program. What would be the problem for this to arise ?

Comment: If the server disconnects after returning the result, NPGSQL goes weird. It is a case of not handling the situation internally within NPGSQL.

Comment: Why do you send query 'select 1 as ConnectionTest\x00'. I mean what scenario is that needed ?

Comment: When the connection returns to connection pool, NPGSQL is sending ' unlisten *' and 'select 1 as ConnectionTest\x00'. It doesn't seem alright to do this. It wont save me time.

Comment: Hi, I tried your sample here and couldn't reproduce the problem as you are getting. I tried on Mono and windows 7. What is the Npgsql version you are using and which runtime? About the select 1, it is done to test if the connection is ok before returning it back to the pool. unlisten * is to clear any notification the client app may have setup so the connection is returned clean to the pool.

Comment: Also note that in your edited example you are not closing the reader. Would you mind to give it a try closing to see if the problem appears again?

Comment: But the example in the manuals dint state it to. And moreover, When making the reader disposable, its anyways safely disposed. I have rectified this by making server being disconnected to this a few more seconds. But my suggestion to you will be to handle that exception. I would suggest you load test it with parallel running threads and a few more sequential(heavy load) and disconnecting on the server side. You will be able to reproduce this. In my case, it is the case disconnecting after sending the result.It disconnects itself after sending the result for the query and disconnecting.

Comment: Its done internally in someways which I can't control as of now. And as a matter of fact in c++ , libpq handles this case. It's my suggestion to handle such a case of handling it. Thanks. Keep the Npgsql going ! We all would like to see a best provider. Currently I see it as the only .Net provider for postgresql.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior In the edited example, it worked when I dint use it with the disposable. Ofcourse, closing is correct if not used with disposable. But disposable is perfect !

Comment: You are correct. Disposable is the way to go. I just asked you to close and see if you get the problem in order to try to reproduce the problem as using construction just calls dispose() method of the reader. But now I understood the problem. I'll try to reproduce it and see how I can fix it.

Comment: Would you mind to fill a bug report about that and add a pointer to this page for more information? That would help us track this problem down. Just check: bugs.npgsql.org Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure ! Cheers. Keep up the great work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Npgsql doesn't handle connection interuptions if you are using datareader with the Idisposable. If the server is terminating the connection before it is communicating to the application and when the connection returns to the connection pool , it goes to the server to check the connection and by this time, the datareader doesn't get disposed properly. In a multi-threaded environment, this will come up in unfortunate circumstances. If the server is disconnecting itself from an connection, it should not terminate so immediately that the Npgsql is not able to communicate back to it. Increase the server's disconnecting time to be higher. Mine is a case of disconnecting the server abruptly forcibly.

Solution : Npgsql should handle the exception internally which is not yet present.